# GridView always with the same values at any time

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I will try to explain what I would like to achieve, since I can't find nothing on internet because I don't really know if something like this exists.

In ASP .NET is there a possibility to create a GridView and manually put some values that remain on that page like forever. So if I access the same page from a different PC in a different day I see always the GridView that I created before.

I'm asking because I know I can do it with a DataBase, but I would like to know if there is something more simple to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this. If it doesn't work google something like "C# ASP.NET Static Gridview"

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="YourText">
<ItemTemplate>
    Your text
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```